# Как достать значения из HashMap

Tags: java

Задача: достать из Map заработную плату сотрудника

Как я пытался, но в итоге некорректно работает:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Department> entry : departments.entrySet()) {
               List list = Department.getEmployeeList();
            }
```

То, где хранится:

```
Map<String, Department> departments = new HashMap<>();
```

В каком виде:

```
Первый - Department{name='Первый', employeeList=[Employee{salary=13000.13, name='Кошкин'}, Employee{salary=13000.13, name='Петрович Котович Кот'}, Employee{salary=20000.0, name='Сидоров'}, Employee{salary=40000.0, name='Пушкин'}]}
Второй - Department{name='Второй', employeeList=[Employee{salary=10000.0, name='Петров'}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, Department> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Department>();
hashMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.getEmployeeList().forEach((c) ->
    System.out.println("Отдел - " + k + " salary - " + c.getSalary())));
```

Или так:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Department> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<Employee> employees = entry.getValue().getEmployeeList();   
}
```

Если предположить, что hashMap это ваш объект, то данный код выведет все з/п сотрудников в объекте hashMap.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111380/discussion-on-answer-by-alekseigaile-----hashmap).

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik мне необходимы данные из чата, но когда перехожу по ссылке, то ничего нет

Comment: @Blacit как так?

Comment: Текст, который меня "приветствует" и также картинка из Star Trek: Page not found
We couldn't find the page you requested. We did, however, find some guys with an even more serious problem.

Try searching for a particular message
Browse the available rooms
Occasionally, messages or rooms may be removed for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etcetera.

If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.